# How to close CallKit background green notification

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I'm facing an issue as **call is not connected** but this CallKit UI Notification (or whatever it is called) remains in the background and I can't kill it. It is obvious that I can't call `performEndCallAction` as cal is not connected and I can't get uuid of call.

How else to kill/dismiss this?

Following is my start call action code.

When error happens following is log:

callButtonTapped

Performing call

2019-01-13 20:36:40.739368+0000 [6789:930051] StartCallAction transaction request successful

Before reportCall

After reportCall

```
// MARK: Call Kit Actions
func performStartCallAction(uuid: UUID, handle: String) {
    let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: handle)
    let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: callHandle)
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)

    callKitCallController.request(transaction)  { error in
        if let error = error {
            NSLog("StartCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            // Try ending the call if the green bar disappears
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Call failed", message: "Something went wrong. Please close app, restart and try again. Contact support if problem persists.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (action) in

                }
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                alert.view.tintColor = .purpleColour
//                alert.view.layoutIfNeeded() //avoid Snapshotting error
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            return
        }

        NSLog("StartCallAction transaction request successful")

        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
        callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle
        callUpdate.supportsDTMF = true
        callUpdate.supportsHolding = true
        callUpdate.supportsGrouping = false
        callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = false
        callUpdate.hasVideo = false

        print("Before reportCall")
        self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate)
        print("After reportCall")
    }
}
```

[image: Call Kit Notification]

Comment: Call in progress UI is only shown when a call is accepted, please share relevant code so we can further investigate.

Comment: No that's not correct. In my case call is not even initiated let alone connected. I'm using twilio quickstart code https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift This is a random error which normally happens when app is started first (or first and few more times) after installation. I've been searching solution, contacted twilio support but everyone just assumes that call is already started. Not sure how to explain more in details? Call Kit fires but call isn't initiated, is it not a possible scenario?

Comment: I'm using Twilio video with callKit in my app too, I sure have seen some UI bugs but not exactly what you are describing, can you record a video of the bug please ?

Comment: I've updated my question with code with log when error happens. It logs "StartCallAction transaction request successful" but call doesn't connect and CallKit is started. Twilio doesn't register any call. When I kill the app callKit shows error - Call failed. As I've said earlier this happens only first few times after fresh install. It doesn't occur afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

you have to request the end transaction with callkit. that will fix you issue

```
let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: uuid)
let transaction = CXTransaction()
callController.request(transaction) { error in
    if let error = error {
        // End call transaction  failed
    } else {
        // End call transaction succeeded. this will hide the green color bar
    }
}
```